# Getting array value from index using Lua C Api

Tags: c, lua, lua-table, lua-api

I have this array:

```
a = {{4,2,2,6}, {2,1,1,2}}
```

How can I retrieve an index from that array to a C program?

For example:

```
a[1] -- {4,2,2,6}
a[1][2] -- 2
```

Comment: Lua arrays start at 1, not 0.

Comment: It's a common problem when you use a lot of languages with 0 started indexes everyday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
lua_getglobal(L,"a")
lua_rawgeti(L,-1,1)
lua_rawgeti(L,-1,2)
```

After this, the value of `a[1][2]` will be on the top of the stack. The stack will also contain `a` and `a[1]`, which you may want to pop when you're done (they're left on the stack in case you want to retrieve multiple values).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`lua_gettable`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_gettable) method. There are a few important notes, however:

1. Lua arrays start at index 1, not 0.
2. You'll need to push the index onto the lua stack via [`lua_pushinteger`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pushinteger).
3. The key is "replaced" with the indexed element.

Comment: 1 - It's a common problem when you use a lot of languages with 0 started indexes everyday.